# How To Treat Genexus Warnings in KB as UNSTABLE build in Jenkins/MSBuild

Tags: genexus

Is it possible to detect (and display) Genexus warnings when building a KB from a Jenkins Job?

I tried using the %ERROR_LEVEL% variable, but the value is '0' even if there where warnings in the build process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it´s a decent workaround: https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/

This plugin can be configured as a post-build action (in freestyle jobs or declarative pipelines), parsing the build output and looking for the pattern "warning :"

Sample rules file used:

```
# GX build errors
error /error :/

# GX build warnings
warning /warning :/
```